# Get Azure IOT Hub connection string from UWP app on provisioned device

Tags: azure-iot-hub, windows-iot-core-10

I have a Raspberry Pi running Windows IOT Core, which has been provisioned to an Azure IOT Hub. I'm writing a UWP app and I want to send messages to the IOT Hub, which I think I need `Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.DeviceClient` to do. DeviceClient needs a connection string, which I can hardcode in the app for testing.

How do I:

1. Check if the device the app is running on is provisioned to an IOT Hub?
2. Get the connection string for the IOT Hub?

I can't know this information at compile time, and I don't want to rebuild my application for every device/deployment.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.DeviceClient is IoT Hub Device SDKs. It is used to send telemetry to your IoT hub, and optionally receive messages, job, method, or twin updates from your IoT hub.  But if you want to get the connection string for the IoT Hub and check if the device is provisioned to an IoT Hub, you need to use [IoT Hub Service SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-csharp)s. It enables you to build backend applications to manage your IoT hub, and optionally send messages, schedule jobs, invoke direct methods, or send desired property updates to your IoT devices or modules. But you also need to set the DeviceId and iot hub connection string in your app.
It is not recommended to generated the connection string in device client end. The sdk supports UWP app to run on Windows IoT Core.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write, but I asked the question because I've already seen all those docs and still can't figure out which APIs to use. The IoT Hub Service SDK has APIs to receive d2c messages and send c2d messages, so I don't see why I'd use it on my device which I want to send telemetry from. I don't see APIs to check if the device the code is currently running on is provisioned or not, and if so, how to create a DeviceClient. How do device manufacturers making thousands of devices use IoT Hub? It's not scalable to build a custom deployment for every device.

Comment: @zivkan, in this scenario, you may use [Azure IoT Hub Device Provisioning Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-dps/) . DPS simplifies the enrollment process by enabling organizations to automatically register and provision millions of devices in a secure and scalable manner to IoT Hub.

Comment: @MichaelXu-MSFT do you know where there is a code sample to send telemetry once the device has been provisioned with DPS? All of the code samples here seem bent on manual provisioning: https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-c/tree/master/iothub_client/samples

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want to try to check out the UWP Bridge. It is a WinRT library that can be used to connect to the Device Agent and read the connection string from the TPM.

You can build the DMBridgeComponent library from the azure-client-tools repo on GitHub (https://github.com/ms-iot/azure-client-tools) and then reference it from your UWP app.

Then, to read your connection string you just need the following code:

```
using DMBridgeComponent;
...

var tpm = new TpmBridge();

// Get connection string from TPM
var slotNumberValue = 0;
var connectionString = tpm.GetConnectionString(slotNumberValue, 36000);
```

Set the `slotNumberValue` to whatever slot you used when you provisioned your device. It is usually 0 by default.

There is more information here (https://github.com/ms-iot/azure-client-tools/blob/master/docs/device-agent/uwp-bridge.md). That's where I found the sample code.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/28945358)

Comment: I edited to add the relevant sample code that was in the link to the answer.